# Update one mysql column when another is edited

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to make a datetime field that automatically gets updated with the current time only if there was a change to a certain field.

It seems I have a syntax error.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER last_progress_date
ON wp_task_mgr
AFTER UPDATE  
AS BEGIN
   IF UPDATE (progress_percentage)
   SET last_progress_date = GETDATE()
END
```

Comment: You want to change the last_progress_date only or some other fields ?\

Comment: For now only `last_progress_date` that gets the date when the `progress_percentage` is updated/edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future reference, I found the answer here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125203/simple-trigger-to-update-two-columns-in-one-table

**MySQL query:**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trig_1 before insert
ON  <table_name> FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   IF   new.due_date is not null and new.end_date='' then
        set new.end_date=new.due_date;
   end if;
      IF   new.end_date is not null and new.due_date='' then
        set new.due_date=new.end_date;
   end if;

END;
//


DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trig_2 before update
ON  <table_name> FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 

   IF   new.due_date <>old.due_date then
        set new.end_date=new.due_date;
   end if;
      IF   new.end_date <> old.end_date then
        set new.due_date=new.end_date;
   end if;

END;
//
```